# kafka new api 0.10 doesn't provide a list of stream and consumer objects per topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Previously I have been using 0.8 API. When you pass topics list to it, it returns a map of streams (one entry per topic). This allows me to spawn a separate thread and assign each topic's stream to it. Having too much data in each topic, spawning a separate thread helps multi tasking.

```java
//0.8 code sample
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap =  
consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
```

I want to upgrade to 0.10. I checked `KafkaStreams` and `KafkaConsumer` classes. `KafkaConsumer` object takes config properties and provide the subscribe method that takes topics List and its return type is void. I cannot find a way where I can get a handle to each topic.

```java
KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
consumer.subscribe(topicsList);
conusmer.poll(long ms)
```

`KafkaStreams` on the other hand seems to have the same problem.

```java
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
String [] topics = new String[] {"topic1", "topic2"};
KStream<byte[], byte[]> source = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, topics);
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
streams.start();
```

There is `source.foreach()` method available but it is a stream of all topics. Anyone, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using a multi threaded consumer is tricky, thus the pattern you employed in `0.8` is hopefully well designed :)

Best practice is to use a single threaded consumer and thus, there is "no need" to separate different topics if a single consumer subscribes to a list of topics at once. Nevertheless, while consuming the record, the record object provides information about from which topic it originates from (it carries this metadata). Thus, you could theoretically dispatch a record according to its topics to a different thread for the actual processing (even if this is not recommended!).

Kafka scales out via *partitions*, thus, if a single-threaded consumer is not able to handle the load, you should start multiple consumers (as a *consumer group*) to scale out your consumer processing capacity.

A more general question: if you want to process data per topic, why not using multiple consumers each subscribing to a single topic each?

Last but not least, in Apache Kafka `0.10+` the *Kafka Streams* API is a newly introduced stream processing library -- though it must not be confused with 0.8 `KafkaStream` class (hint, there is no "s"). Both are completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: Answering your question, Yes, I'm going to create multiple consumers, each per topic. It is just that it doesn't feel right do create connection everytime for a new topic as compared to calling createMessageStreams(topicMapCount) from old api which returns map of streams. Anyways, thanks for a detail answer.